# Do I need to have a static instance of Logger in all my classes to implement log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Log4j perfectly works in conjunction with my application, but my question is that is there 
any other ever efficient approach to implementing it rather than having the following "logger" instance in all classes of my application?

```
public Class myClassName{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myClassName");

    public String myMethod(){
        try{
              ....
        }catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error("Location:MyMethod:" + e.getMessage());
             return "failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can further mark it as `final` variable. Other than that, there is nothing much you can do, since you need a logger instance for every class

Comment: what is in-efficient?  You could put the logger in a super class

Comment: I reckon putting it in a super class would not be a good idea as it would force me to extend a super class and being unable to inherit from any other class.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a singleton pattern here?. One logger instance for all classes. Logger.getLogger() should return the same instance of Logger.

Comment: @TheLostMind whats your idea about Simulant's and J888's answers?

Answer (score 2):

You could use one Logger for all your classes with the draw back that your log messages no longer show which of your classes called the logger, because all classes are using the same logger with a single name. `Logger.getLogger("myClassName")` is used to set the name of the logger to the class name so the classname is easily added to the log message by getting the loggers name.

This will also work, but is not recommanded:

```
public Class MyLogger{
    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLoggerName");
}
```

--

```
public Class myClassName{
    public String myMethod(){
        try{
              //....
        }catch (Exception e) {
             MyLogger.logger.error("Location:MyMethod:" + e.getMessage());
             return "failed";
        }
    } 
}
```

I think you could add the class name by reflection (even if you just use one logger) but this would be very slow and is also not recommanded for productive use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, whats your idea about J888's answer? Another question is that whats your suggestion for production? should I keep separate instances for each class? I have almost 100 classes.

Comment: @Simulant - I don't understand... He can use the stack trace of the current thread to get all the information he needs.

Comment: J888's version is similar to mine, just a bit more complicated but still one logger for all classes.
@TheLostMind: yes but `getStackTrace` can be blocked by the `SecurityManager` or not supported by some virtual machines.
In production I would use one logger per class.

Comment: @Simulant - One logger per class is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a static instance of the logger in the class.

It is better if you add final modifier since it is going to stay constant through all your instances. It is a good programming practice.

`private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ZPAction.class.getName());`

Answer (score 1):

As TheLostMind suggested, you can use a code like following:

```
public class Logging {
    private static Logging instance;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Logging");

    private Logging(){
    }

    public static synchronized Logging getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Logging();

        return instance;
    }

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to log messages, you need to have a log instance. Thus the following line is needed.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myClassName");
```

Alternatively, you could use Aspect Oriented Programming of some sort.

Following link provides an example using Spring AOP
http://www.fiveminutes.eu/logging-with-spring-aop/

Comment: Don't you think using a seperate Logging framework isn't "Seperation Of Concerns" / "AOP" within itself?